# How to create a Pattern to find sequences of *.ABS?

Tags: java, regex

I want to create a `Pattern` in Java which will return true for this lines:

> some_stuff.ABS
>
> hellomynameis.ABS
>
> any_string_or_number.ABS

I tried to use `*.ABS` as Pattern but it didn't work..

Comment: try \w+.[A][B][S] im not good in this either so i choose to comment rather than answering

Comment: @BhavikShah - Several issues with your pattern. First, it won't work properly unless you escape the `.` (otherwise it would match "CABS"). Second, `[A][B][C]` is exactly the same as `ABC`, so there's no need to use character classes here. A better version of your pattern would be `\w+\.ABC` (or, as a Java String, `"\\w+\\.ABC"`). Then, OP might want to match non-word characters before the ".ABC", so `.` might be better than `\w`. Finally, OP might also want to match the string ".ABC" (nothing before it), so `*` might be bettern than `+`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FIrst, you would need to match everything till `.ABS`, for that you can use a `dot(.)` with 0 or more occurrences(`*` quantifier). And then to match `.ABS`, you would need `\\.ABS`.

You can use this: -

```
.*\\.ABS
```

Of course, if you just want to match string that ends with `.ABS`, then `String.endsWith` would be a better choice. You don't really need Regex here.

Comment: If you're using `Pattern.matches`, you don't need the `^` and `$` anchors in the regex; it will attempt to match the entire string anyway.

Comment: @TedHopp.. Oh, yeah. forgot that.

Comment: @RohitJain doesn't work(  java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Dangling meta character '*' near index 0
*\\.ABS

Comment: @VextoR.. Notice a `dot(.)` before `*`.. It is `.*` and not just `*`

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to find every String that *ends with* `ABS`, then do

```
if (line.endsWith(".ABS")) {
  // do your stuff
}
```

Or, for real life strings:

```
if (line.trim().toUpperCase().endsWith(".ABS")) {
  // do your stuff
}
```

Comment: You're missing a closing parenthesis in each `if`

Comment: That was a special Java dialect where we don't need the last closing paranthesis before the beginning of an if block anym... errr .. thanks for correcting :D